# Test no response from server

Tags: android

I'm making a request in a web service.

How am I going to test the case where there is no response from server ( cause maybe server is down ) ?

I mean how can I test it on emulator : is there a way I can send a request and block responses to see how my app is handling this case? Also what should I do in such a case?

Comment: If you're in emulator, just disconnect networking on your host computer - disable wifi and unplug network cable.  _what should I do in such a case_  - this is something you should decide based on the requirements of your application.  Maybe display an error message to the user, maybe wait and retry again later, maybe just default to something local

Comment: you can toogle network connection in emulator. Also you should have timeouts.

Comment: By toggling network connection in emulator I get an exception in the request I make. I'm using Kaltura service and the error is : `E/com.kaltura.client.KalturaClientBase: Fatal transport error: Unable to resolve host "www.kaltura.com": No address associated with hostname` . I want to test the case where I won't get a response. Is it a timeout error ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code :

```
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = getClient();

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = httpclient
                    .getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry();
            schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https",
                    new TlsSniSocketFactory(), 443));
            URI website = new URI(getString(R.string.u3));

            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                    .getEntity().getContent()));


            result = in.readLine();
            // Log.d(TAG, "Version Check result = " + result);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Log.e(TAG, "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }
```

You need to set a timeout & when the server is down, it will probably go in the Catch block where you can do whatever you want to do when the server is down / you receive no response from the server

Answer (score 0):

```
                StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,reg_url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                            String message=jsonObject.getString("message"); //message is to be send by server
                            builder.setTitle("Server Response");
                            Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
```